# Select column that has the fewest NA values

Tags: r, select, dplyr, na

I am working with a data frame that produces two output columns.  One column always has more NA values than the other column, but not in any predictable fashion.  here is my question, how can I use dplyr to select the column with the fewest number of NA values.  I was thinking of utilizing which.min to decide, but not sure how to put it all together.  Note that both columns contain na values, and I want to select the one with the fewest of those values.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `dplyr` and `purrr`.

inside `which.min` you first calculate the number of NA's in the columns with `map` (can be as many columns as you have in your data.frame. The `keep` part returns only those columns which actually have NA's. The `which.min` returns the named vector of which we take the name and supply it to the `select` function of `dplyr`.

I have outlined the code a bit so you can easily see which parts belong where.

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)


df %>% select(names(which.min(df %>% 
                                map(function(x) sum(is.na(x))) %>% 
                                keep(~ .x > 0)
                             )
                    )
              )
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(a = c(rep(c(NA, 1:5), 4)),      # df with different NA counts/col
             b = c(rep(c(NA, NA, 2:5), 4)))



df %>% 
  summarise_all(funs(sum(is.na(.))))         # NA counts
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>       a     b
#>   <int> <int>
#> 1     4     8

df %>%                                       # answer
  select_if(funs(which.min(sum(is.na(.)))))
#> # A tibble: 24 x 1
#>        a
#>    <int>
#>  1    NA
#>  2     1
#>  3     2
#>  4     3
#>  5     4
#>  6     5
#>  7    NA
#>  8     1
#>  9     2
#> 10     3
#> # ... with 14 more rows
```

Created on 2018-05-25 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).