# Select column that has the fewest NA values in Python

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

Would anyone know how to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50496618/select-column-that-has-the-fewest-na-values) in Python instead of R? Say trying to pick the 'SETTLE' column with a data frame `HSITest3` like this:

| Date | BID | ASK | TRDPRC_1 | SETTLE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-07 | <NA> | <NA> | <NA> | 2910 |
| 2022-11-08 | <NA> | <NA> | <NA> | 2958 |
| 2022-11-09 | <NA> | <NA> | 3089 | 3089 |
| 2022-11-10 | <NA> | <NA> | <NA> | 3385 |
| 2022-11-11 | <NA> | <NA> | <NA> | 2382 |

I know this works, but I was looking for something less crude:

```
pdseries = HSITest3.isna().sum(axis=0)
HSITest3[pdseries[pdseries==(min(pdseries))].index[0]]
```

Comment: I am assuming you want to exclude the first and last column?

Comment: I also tried to ask this question with a markdown table but Stak wouldn't let me and forced me to publish it with this text render...

Comment: Hi @It_is_Chris, thank you for the rapid coment!
No, I would like it to return this:

Date
2022-11-07    2910
2022-11-08    2958
2022-11-09    3089
2022-11-10    3385
2022-11-11    2382
Name: SETTLE, dtype: Int64

Comment: `HSITest3[HSITest3.isna().sum(axis=0).idxmin()]`? If you want all columns, then your approach is fine. If you want to drop based on a number of NaNs, see `dropna` with a threshold

Comment: That's it! I knew there was something like that. `idxmin` was what I couldn't find. Thank you!